# Whats "David Guetta" is saying in French?

Tags: prononciation

David Guetta is the first person who did wireless bungee jump. Brave person, amazing job done.

Before going for the task he said something in French to his family, which was very cute. I want to remember these words forever but dont get the pronunciation correct. Seems "Bizu Vizu" he said.

Whats the correct pronunciation and how to write it in French?

Listen here at 1:48 - 1:49.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M6M1ZDo8N8

Comment: @Downvoter, if you downvote it without specifying the reason, you would be considered as "rant" and I wont get what was wrong, so I repeat it again. It seems being a "responsible" stack user you dont want that. So please compromise with your "peeve", "rant", "ego" and be cool just like others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He said « Bisou Bisou » which mean « Kiss Kiss »

Here you can find an example of the « ou » pronunciation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93WWMeSD5V0

In this exercice they explain the difference between « ou » and « u » which can be confusing for english people

Answer (score 2):

He said : "Bisous bisous, ciao ciao."

Bisous \bi.zu\ means *kiss* while ciao \tʃa.o\,\tʃaw\ means *bye* (directly taken from Italian).